# Is it possible to dynamically refer to a package property in Go?

Tags: go

I'm primarily a PHP developer, and recently I started looking into Go. In PHP, I can do something like this:

```
<?php

class TestClass {
    public function testMethod() {
        echo "Hello!\n";
    }
}

$obj = new TestClass();
$method_name = "testMethod";
$obj->{$method_name}();

?>
```

The output being: `Hello!`.

I understand that the following is not a perfect comparison, since Go does not have classes, but I'm wondering if I can do something similar with exported properties of modules in Go. For example something like this (I understand that this is not valid Go code):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    name := "Println"
    fmt[name]("Hello!")
}
```

Is this in anyway possible? How can something similar be accomplished? Thank you.

*Edit: Changed "module" to "package", since this is the proper name for what I was referring to in Go*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have no idea what is meant by 'module properties' (no such thing is known by the Go specs). Only guessing:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        m := map[string]func(va ...interface{}) (int, error){"Println": fmt.Println}
        m["Println"]("Hello, playground")
}
```

(Also [here](http://play.golang.org/p/FiG-GO4_TO))

---

Output

```
Hello, playground
```

Comment: I guess I misspoke by saying "module". In Go I guess I would be referring to packages. By "properties" I just mean the things that the package exposes. Your solution works, but do you know of any way to do this without creating a map?

Comment: Your answer appears to be the only solution, after finding this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/JWquU5kRjIA

Comment: There's one difference in Go wrt properties of modules/packages. A Go package is not an instance of any Go type. It's only a name scoping concept. IOW, no Go variable can hold a package (instance/reference/...) to be later used by the selector operand `.`. In source code it looks like that (eg. `fmt.Printf`), but that's only the compile time (name) resolution mechanism with no analogy at run time.

Comment: Thank you for the above explanation jnml.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you're looking for "reflection".

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type sayer struct {
    said int
}

func (s *sayer) SayHello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}

func main() {
    s := &sayer{}
    cmd := "SayHello"
    reflect.ValueOf(s).MethodByName(cmd).Call(nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you for the example. I am looking for reflection on a package name however, not a struct.